# Commutative Noetherian prime ideals finitely generated

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

In Bosch's Algebra you're asked to prove that

> every commutative ring R is Noetherian iff every ideal is finitely generated

I think I managed to prove the if part (I write it just to be more explicit and to check it):

Let $a_i$ be an ascending chain of ideals
$a_1\subset a_2\subset\ ...\subset R$

$\bigcup a_i=:a$, and a is still an ideal. Since every ideal is finitely generated by hypothesis, we have:

$a=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_m),\ \alpha_i\in R$
Since the chain is ascending, there is an $n$ such that $\forall i\ \ \alpha_i\ \in a_n$, and thus $a_{m\geq n}=a_n$.

I don't know how to approach the only if part: is there any cardinality-based reasoning?

After this exercise, another one has got me stuck:

> every commutative ring $R$ is Noetherian iff every prime ideal is finitely generated

**Note:** I would be really grateful if it wouldn't be necessary to use concepts such as modules and annihilators in proofs, as I'm not used to them

Comment: Pick an ideal and suppose it is not finitely generated. Fix a infinite set which generates it, and construct from it a strictly increasing infinite sequence of ideals.

Comment: (This is done is 90% of algebra textbooks, so if you are *really* lost, you could google…)

Comment: The title refers to prime ideals, the text doesn't. Are you sure you don't have to prove the more difficult result that $R$ is noetherian if and only if each *prime* ideal is finitely generated?

Comment: @egreg that is asked lather

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I tried to google that, but I always ended up with some works talking about modules or semi-groups, concept with which I'm not used at all yet

Comment: Regarding your second question: I googled "noeyheriam prime ideals fi not otely generayed" and the very first result was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2555402/a-ring-is-noetherian-if-its-prime-ideals-are-ﬁnitely-generated One does not even need to fix horrible typos due to typing too fast on a mobile phone to get the correct answer... I more and more often wonder why people are so bad or so lazy at googling.

Comment: I am beginning to fear that we are becoming a let-me-google-it-for-you site, and probably we should simply stop answering questions which are answered by the first result in the obvious google query.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez As you would had known if you had read not so superficially, the answers uses modules, "with which I'm not used at all yet" (and even action and annihilators, other concepts I've never read of, I apologize for my lack of knowledge). Surely, I could actually have tried to understand what was within my reach, but I thought that creating a new question explicitly without those concepts such as modules would have been constructive for those whom, like me, are not confortable yet with a lot of terminology and ideas of abstract algebra

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Anyway, if you think that these question is "answered by the first result in the obvious google query", I am sure that stop answering is not the best way: instead, as you did, it is much more useful to explain (with such a gentle tone, I have to say...) where these question already has an answer and mark it as a duplicate. In such a way, users will learn the art of googling in which we are all so bad and lazy and will stop to bother with these kind of question. "Every question is a cry to understand the world. There is no such thing as a dumb question"
Only bad-posed que

Comment: Part of what we expect of our users when they ask questions is to do the basic legwork in trying to answer them themselves. In the year 2018 that includes a certain amount of googling. At the very least, providing links to existing related questions with an explanation of *why* they do not answer the question one is asking. You seem to think I superficially read the old answer: I did not — the thing is, I doubt there is value in avoiding modules to do this: they were mostly invented in order to do this sort of thing, in fact.

Comment: On the other hand, greg's argument requires the very minimal information about modules imaginable. It would be more productive to ask about what an annihilator is (after googling: I looked and the wikipedia page on the subject seems to be quite good) and whatever else you are missing, really. If you **really** need to avoid modules for some reason (you could be trying to prove something similar about an exotic type of algebras for which there are no modules, say) then explaining in your question what that reason is would be a good idea. If you aren't used to modules, this is a good opportunity

Comment: Finally, it is true that there is no dumb question, but there *is* a repeated question.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez The exercises are in the second chapter, where annihilator and modules have not been introduced yet. Thus, in order to answer to the exercise, I cannot use them, or at least I could non use them, in the same way in which it would be a wrong answer in elementary calculus to prove asserts using Lebesgue. Moreover, I prefer to study on a book than on a site like Wikipedia. Finally, I totally agree with you about the repeated question, but I hope you are convinced that mine isn't one

Comment: Read a book if you prefer it to Wikipedia, and learn what an annihilator is. It will take more or less then same 30 seconds. The only modules that appear in greg's argument ar ideals of the ring and quotients of ideals: that means that one can. if one really wants to, remove all references to the word module very easily. The resulting argument will only be more verbose (this is one of the reasons modules entered the study of rings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: suppose $a$ is not finitely generated; then there exists $x_1\in a$ and $(x_1)\ne a$, so there is $x_2\in a\setminus(x_1)$ and $(x_1)\subsetneq(x_1,x_2)$. Go on.

Comment: Ok, I got it: $(x_1)\subset (x_1,x_2)\subset...\subset a$, but since $R$ in Noetherian, then there is an $n: (x_1,...,x_n)=(x_1,...,x_n,x_{n+1})=a$ right?